# display number of message dynamically using javascript or asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, social-media, email-notifications

I will do my best to explain my problem to avoid people pointing me into different directions.

I got an assignment from business people. I don't know the terminology. It is very similar to email notification, message notification on facebook, notification on social media games.

For example, people are sending 20 email messages 5 minutes ago. the screen will display 20 (see attachment). Now, 3 more messages have arrived, the web page should update the number to 23.

Facebook has similar concepts when our friends like/comment message. The notification changes. Same thing is true on social media game. Any status changes on our game, it will reflect it.

I kind of have idea on how to do it cosmetically (on CSS). How to do it using javascript/asp.net. Do I need to postback in order to refresh the message. I never pay attention to that on facebook/yahoo email/social media games. All I know is something is happening, the webpage is updating the status.

Sorry the question is too broad. If someone can help me to point to the right direction, I appreciate any help

[image: number of email message]

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 introduced a very interesting concept call Server-Sent Events in which server can dynamically connect to the client and send data.

Eg:

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.asp");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data + "<br>";
};
```

And on server side you can write,

```
<%
    Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream"
    Response.Expires = -1
    <!--Writing "data:" is important-->
    Response.Write("data: The server time is: " & now())
    Response.Flush()
%>
```

However, some old browsers may not support this.

One other way to accomplish this task is to use Ajax call as,

```
function checkNewMessages(totalMessages){
return $.ajax({
    url: 'demo.asp',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    data: {
       totalMessages: totalMessage;
    }
});
```

}

```
checkNewMessages(totalMessages).success(function (data) {
    // display the data wherever you want
});

    //Checking for new messages every 5 seconds
    setInterval(checkNewMessages(totalMessages,5000));
```

Whatever you write within your `Write()` in server side will be displayed here. Now to constantly check for the new messages you can call the above ajax function with the help of `setInterval()`

Comment: Thanks. for ajax call, I need to write setInterval to call asmx webmethod to update status and display on html. I notice you use aspx extension. I assume I can use asmx on both solution. Right?

Comment: @user12345 Yes and with the setInterval() you can specify how frequent should you check for new messages

Comment: For HTML 5, do I need to use setinternal, or the function will update itself. Can I use asmx on html 5method. Thanks

Comment: @user12345 No you don't need to use setInterval() for it as the server will automatically connect with the client. Here is a link which explains SSE(Server-Side Events) in detail http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

Comment: Thanks, I will try both methods and see which is better. I am more familiar with ajax, but I will give a try HTML 5 method.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, depending on how real time you need it to be.

The most common way is to use `JavaScript` with an `XmlHttpRequest` to call an `ASP.NET` page which returns the number of messages, I recommend you use a `JSON` object for this. The benefit of this approach allows you to request data from the server without the user experiencing a full page refresh. You can use JavaScript to set it to call every x seconds depending on your requirements.

Collectively that is known as `AJAX`, using a JavaScript library such as `JQuery` can make this much easier.

Comment: Thanks. Regardless of solution, I have to use setInterval, so the webpage can update the status every x number of seconds. I am not familiar XmlHttpRequest , but I use ajax to call webmethod all the time. Which one is better.

Comment: You don't 'have' to use setInterval at all, you could use web sockets or something like SignalR to push from the server to the client in real time, but that may be overkill for your requirements. Ajax and setInterval seems like what you need. XmlHttpRequest is how ajax calls are made with just JavaScript, stick with ajax calls via jQuery, it simplifies things and means you don't have to worry about browser differences.